# Log4j2 (beta9) How to configure custom layout for FileAppender?

Tags: log4j2

Can someone tell me, How to configure custom layout for FileAppender?

Can anyone tell me, how to configure custom layout for FileAppender?
I'm created copy of HTMLLayout and made some changes there (it's cannot be extends because it's final class) and now I want use this layout, but I don't know how  :(

This error is showed with bellow listed configuration:
ERROR File contains an invalid element or attribute "ibtrader.log4j2.MYHTMLLayout"

Here is my log4j2.xml configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration strict="true" monitorInterval="30">
  <appenders>   
    <appender name="Console" type="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <layout type="PatternLayout"  pattern="%highlight{%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n}" />
    </appender>        
    <appender name="DEBUG_FILE" type="File" fileName="logs/errors.txt" >
        <layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n}" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="HTMLAppender" type="File" fileName="logs/mainlog.html">
        <layout type="ibtrader.log4j2.MYHTMLLayout" charset="UTF-8" title="IBTRader logs" locationInfo="true" />
    </appender>        
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
   <root level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_FILE" level="WARN" />   
    <appender-ref ref="HTMLAppender" /> 
   </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: FIXED: Add packages attribute into configuration element to load specific classes

Answer (score 0):

The comments mention this is already fixed but just for completeness, a (simplified) configuration with a custom MYHTMLLayout plugin could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- the packages attribute contains a comma-separated list 
     of the packages that Log4J2 will scan for custom plugins. -->
<configuration packages="ibtrader.log4j2">
  <appenders>
    <appender name="HTMLAppender" type="File" fileName="logs/mainlog.html">

        <!-- Each plugin has a *name*, declared with annotation on the 
             plugin implementation class. 
             The plugin name does not need to match the class name.
             The plugin name needs to match the *type* attribute in the config.

             For example:

             package ibtrader.log4j2;
             import ...;
             @Plugin(name="MYHTMLLayout", category="Core", 
                     elementType="layout", printObject=true)
             public class MyHTMLLayoutImpl extends AbstractStringLayout {...
         -->
        <layout type="MYHTMLLayout" charset="UTF-8" title="IBTRader logs" locationInfo="true" />
    </appender>        
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
   <root level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="HTMLAppender" /> 
   </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend AbstractStringLayout, setting the @Plugin properties with category = "Core", elementType = "layout" and name="The name of the class itself that should be refered from the configuration file" (i.e.: "ExtHtmlLayout")

You could just copy the whole class HtmlLayout from the sources and change whatever you want, for example, the time in millis column to the time in hours.

Define the package property in "Configuration" tag to use the package to the extended class you have created.

```
Finally, just call the new layout from the configuration file:
<ExtHtmlLayout/>
```